# Ticks Graphs Forest picture is not entirely drawn in the tikzpicture bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, forest

I am trying to create a graph of a tree using the forest library of tikz graphs. When compiling the whole picture moves out of the tikz bounding box. Any suggestions how to center the picture?

The tikzpicture in question is this (yes, its not really minimal, but should still be simple enough.

Since it uses the tikz graphs library, lualatex is necessary for compiling.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage[linguistics,external]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,shapes.geometric,arrows,hobby,backgrounds,calc,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle]
  \newcommand{\plus}{\color{darkgreen}{$+$}}
  \newcommand{\minus}{\color{darkred}{$-$}}
% [every node/.style={edge={thick,blue}}]
\colorlet{darkred}{red!80!black}
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!80!black}
   \begin{forest}
   %aligns the bottom lines
   for tree={
    where n children=0{tier=terminal,!u.tier=second,!uu.tier=third}{},
   }
   [ {$\{m_7,m_{11}\}$}
     [{$\{m_8,m_9\}$}
       [{$\{m_1,m_2,m_4\}$}
         [{$\{m_1,m_3\}$}
            [1][2],
         ]
         [{$\{\dots\}$}
           [3][4\\\plus]
         ]
       ]
       [{$\{m_7\}$}
         [ {$\{m_7\}$}
           [{5\\\minus},for ancestors={edge={darkred,very thick}},edge={darkred,very thick}][6]
         ]
         [ {$\{\dots\}$}
           [7\\\plus][8\\\plus]
         ]
       ]
     ]
    [{$\{\dots\}$}
     [{$\{\dots\}$}[9\\\minus][10]]
     [{$\{\dots\}$}[11][12\\\minus]]
    ]
   ]
   \end{forest}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that nothing here requires the `graphs` or `graphdrawing` libraries (or the other Ti*k*Z libraries, except `backgrounds`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it *without* the `tikzpicture` environment. If you need a frame use the simple `\fbox`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solution was too simple.. Just out of curiosity, what went wrong in combination with the tikzpicture environment?

Comment: I am not a tikz user, but I suppose that forest internally uses a `tikzpicture` environment, too.

Comment: @MartinR You're nesting `tikzpicture`s, which isn't supported, for just the reason Herbert gave. However, you can still use Ti*k*Z to draw the frame if you wish - you don't need to resort to `\fbox`. (That is, `\fbox` is a good solution if you want something simple enough, but you can do fancy Ti*k*Z stuff if you so desire.)

Comment: @cfr the background rectangle was only to illustrate the mismatch between the positioning between my tree and the tikzpicture environment - something I didn't notice the absence of in those introductory examples to forest..

Answer (score 0):

Forest uses `tikzpicture` and nesting them isn't supported and generally gives weird results. Hence, Herbert's answer is spot on. However, there are a couple of other potential pitfalls in your code - primarily the use of `where` inside `for tree`. So, here's a somewhat cleaned up version of your code. I also show how to add a frame using Ti*k*Z, should you wish to do so. Just delete the `tikz+` line to remove it.

You are using `where` in a `for tree` which is not wise. At best, it is inefficient. At worst, it spells trouble and can cause weird effects. This is because `where` already does `for tree`. Either use just `where` or use `if` rather than `where`.

You can avoid cluttering the nodes with `$` by making judicious use of `math content`. You don't want this for the multiline nodes, but it will work for all the non-terminal nodes.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

{% use a group if the definitions should be local (as we're losing the tikzpicture)
  \newcommand{\plus}{\color{darkgreen}{$+$}}%
  \newcommand{\minus}{\color{darkred}{$-$}}%
  \colorlet{darkred}{red!80!black}%
  \colorlet{darkgreen}{green!80!black}%
  \begin{forest}
    %aligns the bottom lines
    % don't nest a where in a for tree as where already does for tree - it can do strange things
    % using math content saves cluttering the nodes with $, but we don't want this for the last level, as these are multiline 
    where n children=0{tier=terminal,!u.tier=second,!uu.tier=third}{math content},
    tikz+={\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);},
    [{\{m_7,m_{11}\}}
      [{\{m_8,m_9\}}
        [{\{m_1,m_2,m_4\}}
          [{\{m_1,m_3\}}
            [1][2]
          ]
          [{\{\dots\}}
            [3][4\\\plus]
          ]
        ]
        [{\{m_7\}}
          [ {\{m_7\}}
            [{5\\\minus},for ancestors={edge={darkred,very thick}},edge={darkred,very thick}][6]
          ]
          [ {\{\dots\}}
            [7\\\plus][8\\\plus]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [{\{\dots\}}
        [{\{\dots\}}[9\\\minus][10]]
        [{\{\dots\}}[11][12\\\minus]]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}%
}

\end{document}
```

The output is no different from Herbert's.

[image: framed cleaned code]